# Is it possible to consume WCF service from same project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, wcf-binding

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application that uses a WCF service within the same project. Ideally I'd like to call out to this service using jQuery. However, I cannot seem to wrap my head around what I'm doing. Should I still create an endpoint in the configuration? Right now I receive the following exception:

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

I can enable anonymous authentication for IIS but I'd prefer to use Windows. When I setup a binding configuration, since there is no endpoint, I'm not sure where to add that configuration to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to reach your WCF service, you will generally need to setup an endpoint. An alternative approach would be to host your service "In-Proc" using the `InProcFactory` clas, which is part of the `ServiceModelEx` library from Juval Löwy available from [the downloads page of his website](http://idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx?tabindex=5&tabid=11) (registration is required to download it, just search for "ServiceModelEx" and click the link). That approach would look like:

```
IMyService proxy = InProcFactory.CreateInstance<MyServiceClass, IMyService>();
proxy.MyMethod();
```

This reduces the configuration if you don't need to do any custom configuration; however, as soon as you hit a boundary with the default configuration, you'll either need to go back to using a configured endpoint, or looking for a way to programmatically update your service's configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an endpoint, but as with all WCF endpoints it doesn't necessarily need to be defined in the config file - you're free to define it in code.

As you're already in a web project, your simplest solution will be to host the WCF service in IIS. This works very easily with a config file, and in .NET 4 most of the configuration is defaulted (a lot simpler than 3.5)

Once your service is defined you need to instantiate a channel or a client. You can use the `svcutil` tool to generate a proxy (using the 'Add New Service Reference...' wizard), or just create a `ChannelFactory`

```
var factory = new ChannelFactory<MyService>(typeof(MyService).FullName);
MyService channel = factory.CreateChannel();

// use the channel as you would a normal instance of the class
var result = channel.MyOperation("hello world");
```

Again, this pattern will retrieve configuration from your `web.config` file. Because your project is both the service and the client, you'll need both sections. This isn't a complete configuration but should give you the idea...

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="MyProject.MyService">
      <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                contract="MyProject.IMyService" />
    </service>
  </services>
  <client>
    <endpoint name="MyProject.MyService" 
              address="http://localhost" 
              binding="basicHttpBinding" 
              contract="MyProject.IMyService" />
  </client>    
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Any difference where he wants to access the service from AJAX?

Comment: Thanks John I veered a little away from that part of the question.  I believe accessing a WCF service using Javascript in the same project should work the same as using Javascript from any other location, but I have no knowledge of using Windows authentication from jQuery.

Comment: The Windows authentication should be pass through if the web app is set to have Windows authentication.